# UNLOAD in Quantum Active Scale

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there any copy redshift data into active scale bucket? There is an option "UNLOAD" in AWS Redshift (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

Is there any similar options in quantum active scale? if not, any other alternatives to achieve this?

I tried boto3 API. it's working as expected but I would like to use UNLOAD function directly from amazon redshift to Quantum active scale.

s3.Bucket(bucketName).put_object(Body = "body", Bucket = bucketName, Key = f'{offset}/test.txt')